# Move rows to another sheet based on a cell criteria not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a vba code to move the entire row to another existing sheet in the next available sheet for one and multiple criteria’s. The file that I am working on is exported from an application and hence has unprintable data. I first trim and clean the range and then run the code. I have 3 problems as of now:

1. The below code that I used to move entire to another sheet based on the value of in column BY which should be blank, then all the lines which has AG has blank was moving from ACCF main sheet to Accounts Missing Info sheet. I had lot of pre and post action macros within the same workbook. I had to change the order of the macros and pos that the below code stopped working. I tried to debug, and there is no error as well.
   2.I also have another code to move entire row from ACCF main sheet to next available column row in Accounts Missing Info sheet with 2 criteria’s. Column F to be “JNTN” and column M to be blank. This was also working fine until I reordered the macros. I have tried many other codes but nothing works.
2. Third problem is, I am using the same code used in point 2 to include a date. I want all rows with criteria 1 = col F to be “TRST” and criteria 2 to be col Z( which is a date) to be opened before jan 5th 2012. I don’t know how to incorporate the date.

I know the best method to use is Autofilter method to filter data and move to another sheet in the next available column. I googled and checked videos but none of them work.

Please help me. One code to use for all the above will be good. Where I can change one to two criteria as per the requirement.

Code 1

```
Sub missingphone()

a = worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(rows.count,1).End(xlup).row
For i = 2 to a
    If worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(i,77).Value= “” then

        Worksheets(“ACCF Main”).rows.copy
        Worksheets(“Accounts missing info”).Activate
        b = worksheets(“Accounts missing info”).cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
        Worksheets(“accounts missing info”).cells(b+1,1).select
        ActiveSheet.paste
        Worksheets(“accf main”).Activate

   End if

Next

Thisworkbook.worksheets(“accf main”).cells(1,1).select

End sub
```

Code 2

```
Sub marriedjoint()

a = worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i=2 to a
    If worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(i,5).Value= “JNTN” And cells(i,13).value=“” then

    Worksheets(“ACCF Main”).rows.copy
    Worksheets(“Accounts missing info”).Activate
    b = worksheets(“Accounts missing info”).cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    Worksheets(“accounts missing info”).cells(b+1,1).select
   Activesheet.paste
   Worksheets(“accf main”).Activate

   End if

    Next

    Thisworkbook.worksheets(“accf main”).cells(1,1).select

    End sub
```

Comment: in your code1 and code2, I think you should write `Sheets("ACCF Main").Rows(i).copy` instead of `Worksheets(“ACCF Main”).rows.copy`

Comment: Still doesn’t work. The column in range should be trimmed and cleaned which is taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly about your code-1 and code-2 :

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim rgJNTN As Range

'set the needed sheet as variable sh1 and sh2
Set sh1 = Sheets("ACCF Main")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Accounts missing info")

'set the range of data in column A of sh1
Set rg = sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    'looped to each blank cell in column BY (column 77)
    For Each cell In rg.Offset(0, 76).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        'copy the entire row of the looped cell into sh2 blank row
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next

    'get the range cells which value is "JNTN" in column E sh1 as rgJNTN variable
    With rg.Offset(0, 4)
        .Replace "JNTN", True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgJNTN = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical) 
        .Replace True, "JNTN", xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
    'loop to each cell (which value is "JNTN") in rgJNTN
    For Each cell In rgJNTN
        'if the looped cell.Offset(0,8) value = "" (column M or column 13, looped cell row)
        'and if the looped cell.offset(0,72) value <> "" (column BY or column 77, looped cell row)
        'then copy the entire row of the looped cell to sh2 blank row
        If cell.Offset(0, 8) = "" And cell.Offset(0, 72).Value <> "" Then cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Not tested in my side.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. The criteria in code 1 and 2 are different. I have 70 types of accounts and 70 different criterias. If I create 70 codes its going to take a long time to run. Instead I would like to include all criteria’s  in the same code if possible but keep them independent. 

I’m getting an error at “for each cell in rg.offset … “. I only see the yellow line. Not sure what it is for. Is there a way I can run this without having to trim and clean the range in question. Any way to include in autofilter method. Any suggestion will be helpful and greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I thought the criteria to check is just the one I see in your code but it turned there are more than 60 criterias beside : `If worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(i,77).Value= “”` and `If worksheets(“ACCF Main”).cells(i,5).Value= “JNTN” And cells(i,13).value=“”`. This is only two criteria.

Comment: You wrote : _Not sure what it is for_ . To know it, you can test it by first adding a line to select/activate the sheet and/or the range. For example `sh1.activate:sh2.activate` after `Set sh1 = Sheets("ACCF Main")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Accounts missing info")`. Or `sh1.activate:rg.select` after `Set rg = sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` , then step run the sub. And also try to see what happen on the sheet after you add a line something like `rg.offset(0,76).select` after activating sh1. And see what happen if you add `rg.Offset(0, 76).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).select`